# Async event writes partial file/stream

Tags: javascript, axios

Im getting stream data to an event. The `data` is being downloaded by `Axios` and its of type `AxiosTransformStream`. The `Axios` request itself is set to have `responseType` of `stream` and im confident that the data is being downloaded correctly (I can test it independently).

The problem is when the stream is passed to an event to be further processed. The snippet below is (should) save the data to a local file:

```js
emitter.on("result", async function (data) {
  const fileWriter = fs.createWriteStream("path/to/save/file.txt");

  data.pipe(fileWriter);

  await new Promise((resolve) => data.on("finish", resolve));

  let a = 1 // breakpoint here is never triggered
})
```

After the above code is ran the file is generated but its incomplete. It is supposed to be ~460Kb but only 65Kb are saved (im guessing only few chunks are actually saved before the `finish` event is called).

The interesting part is that if i put breakpoint right after the `Promise` it is never triggered. If i comment the `Promise` part the breakpoint is triggered.

Im not sure where the problem is.